# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I am running the following code on Raspberry Pi with pi camera, I have the broadcom drivers for it and all, but I am getting an error. Perhaps something to do with the dimensions of the video feed, but I do not know how to set it on Linux.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q):
        break
```

Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, 
file /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 325
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_picam_with_opencv.py", line 10, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:325: error: 
(-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide an id to `VideoCapture`.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Also check the value of `ret`, see if it's `TRUE` or `FALSE`

```
print (ret)
```

**Edit:**

> To capture a video, you need to create a VideoCapture object. Its argument can be either the device index or the name of a video file. Device index is just the number to specify which camera.

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

> To check whether the `cap` has been initialized or not, you can use `cap.isOpened()` function, which returns `True` for successful initialization and `False` for failure.

```
if cap.isOpened() == False:
    print ("VideoCapture failed")
```

> `cap.read()` returns a bool (True/False). If frame is read correctly, it will be True. So you can check end of the video by checking this return value.

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret == False:
    print("Frame is empty")
```

Further reading [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html).

Comment: Could you add some info for the OP so they know what the values of `ret` means?